# Compiling skakdoc.tex, newcomer, new installation

Tags: chess, skak

I'm a newcomer to TeX trying to run `skakdoc.tex` from 
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/skak/doc?lang=en.

I cannot get it to compile correctly using pdflatex. 
It gives

```
! undefined control sequence <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
```

It seems to compile alright with xelatex, though no squares are highlighted. (Expecting highlighted squares based on the ps file in the link and the error)

My setup:
proTeXt, Basic MikTeX installed. Also installed pstricks and other possible related packages.
Using notepad++ to run pdflatex.

Comment: The error persisted with the `-shell-escape` options, so it doesn't appear to be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from another thread:

[How can I get skak to highlight squares](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/how-can-i-get-skak-to-highlight-squares?rq=1)

Due to the `ps` option, we have to do

```
latex skakdoc.tex
dvips skakdoc.dvi
ps2pdf skakdoc.ps
```